# Pass url variables to View Make function in Laravel

Tags: php, templates, laravel, variable-assignment

I have Googled alot and still no solution so far.
My question TLDR: With `View::make()` how to get such `url: example.com/sub/?parameter=1`

Every solution found so far is about passing data in second argument in `View::make('blade-template', $data)` but I'd like to have also `?parameter=1`
Can it be done with making view? Here is what I have now:

```
public function city($location)
{
    if ($location) {
        return View::make('home', array('dummy-array'));
    }
    return View::make('errors.missing');
}
```

And it creates `example.com/new-york`.

Is it possible to achieve such url `example.com/new-york/?parameter=1` I need that so I can check in my blade file if that parameter is set I will open modal (Yes I know i could use session too, but in my case I need it via parameter).

Workaround is to have `return Redirect::to('new-york/?parameter=1')->with('location', $locationCache);` But I already have 1 redirect before, so I'd prefer to use the `View::Make`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View::share('parameter', 1);` wherever you need and this variable would be passed to all views.

Comment: This passes variable to the view itself so I could use it in my blade template file. But what I want is to append to my URL parameters (example.com/?appendthat=1) when doing `View::make`

Comment: Oh, in that case you should use redirect with the checking on parameter existence in query string... View would not help you.